# Plot solutions to differential equations

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I have a combined system of two differential equations. I would like to know how to plot them

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please post complete code (not an image) so that people trying to help can reproduce your results.

Comment: I think you should try to fix the warnings messages being given from `NDSolve` before trying to plot the solutions. It is always best to make sure the solution is obtained OK before trying to process it any more.